# How can I add a search button to my dock on a Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I just saw a tweet where someone had added a search button to the 3 docked software buttons

[image]

**So I'd like to know how to add the search button (or any other) to the dock with the Back, Home and Multitasking buttons**

Is this a setting of the default launcher or done through some app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>They work like normal shortcuts, just long-press the icon and drop it into the recycling bin, and then open the app menu, long-press `Search` and drag it down to the dock.</strike>

Edit: The dock in question is not customizable from the default settings, but it can be patched through ClockworkMod. The most comprehensive customization options I've seen can be found [here](http://android.modaco.com/topic/348762-30-nov-ui-patches-lhs-rhs-both-search-button-when-hidden/).

The files need to be applied through ClockworkMod so the device has to be rooted. Just download the file you prefer, move it to the internal sdcard and apply the update from recovery. Be sure to backup first, just in case.

Comment: I think he means the buttons below that. The ones that used to be hardware buttons, and now are software.

Comment: Oops, that's what I get for reading the question too quickly, confused the work dock with the, well, dock. Would this be what you're looking for: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1355193 ?

Comment: I thought the same thing until I saw the picture, which reminded me that they're no longer hardware buttons.

Comment: That's the thing @onik, care to explain it in more detail in your answer, so others know the solution too?

Comment: Ah so I have to root it anyway, well guess there's no pain in that

Comment: According to [this](http://pocketnow.com/android/can-you-put-a-search-button-in-ice-cream-sandwichs-button-bar) it's also in the MoDaCo ROM.