# How to access functions previously assigned to the hardware Search button on HTC Sensation XE

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-sensation-xe

I presently have an HTC Desire handset which has a physical Search button. If I long-press on that search button I get a pop-up screen titled "Complete action using" and then I have three options of programs to run. I have the options of running my AutoRotate Switch program, running the Quick Compose feature of my SMS program or running a Voice Search.

I find this jolly handy mainly for the auto-rotate Switch fast access.

However, I understand that the HTX Sensation XE handset doesn't have a hardware Search button, ( or maybe no dedicated UI search button at all) so is there an alternative method of getting at this list of application short cuts on the new handset?

Alternatively does the version of Android on the Sensation XE ( ICS I believe) have any kind of QuickLaunch feature that applications can be added to?

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sensation XE (which is externally identical to my Sensation barring colour) does have a hardware search button, located immediately below the touchscreen, furthest to the right:

[image: Image of HTC Sensation]

I haven't noticed a setting on android 4.0 to allow you to customise the behaviour of the button, however.  The default behaviour is to launch the Voice Search App.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Android 4.0, you can adjust the softkey buttons at the bottom of the screen to re-add missing buttons such as search: [How can I add a search button to my dock on a Galaxy Nexus?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16910/how-can-i-add-a-search-button-to-my-dock-on-a-galaxy-nexus)

For lower than Android 4.0.... there's the [SoftKeys app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hoopajoo.android.SoftKeys&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5ldC5ob29wYWpvby5hbmRyb2lkLlNvZnRLZXlzIl0.).

*Note: all of the above require root*